# No wifi adapter found Broadcom BCM43162

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

Ii just installed Ubuntu 22.04 as the only OS. My problem is that the wifi adapter doesn't work or Linux doesn't recognize it for whatever reason.

I'm using this code from another post:

wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
chmod +x wireless-info &&&
./wireless-info

This is the information it gives me: https://pastebin.com/TvL3HNht

```
########## wireless info START ##########
 
Report from: 13 Jul 2022 09:48 CEST +0200
 
Booted last: 13 Jul 2022 00:00 CEST +0200
 
Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000
 
##### release ###########################
 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
 
##### kernel ############################
 
Linux 5.15.0-41-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 14:20:53 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 
Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
 
##### desktop ###########################
 
Ubuntu
 
##### lspci #############################
 
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3829]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
 
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43162 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43162 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0622]
 
##### lsusb #############################
 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0489:e079 Foxconn / Hon Hai BCM2045A0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174f:14f2 Syntek Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b4:0033 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc. M2012K11AG
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 
##### PCMCIA card info ##################
 
##### rfkill ############################
 
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
 
##### secure boot #######################
 
SecureBoot disabled
 
##### lsmod #############################
 
wmi_bmof               16384  0
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
platform_profile       16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    32768  2 wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop
video                  53248  1 ideapad_laptop
 
##### interfaces ########################
 
##### ifconfig ##########################
 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.123.220/24 brd 192.168.123.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 3364sec preferred_lft 3364sec
    inet6 fe80::c657:cf8d:c43d:5256/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 
##### iwconfig ##########################
 
lo        no wireless extensions.
 
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
 
usb0      no wireless extensions.
 
##### route #############################
 
default via 192.168.123.7 dev usb0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.123.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.123.220 metric 100 
 
##### resolv.conf #######################
 
[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']
 
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
 
##### network managers ##################
 
Installed:
 
    NetworkManager
 
Running:
 
root         661       1  0 09:39 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
 
##### NetworkManager info ###############
 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         usb0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm, Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        M2012K11AG
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-41-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/net/usb0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:10.0-usb-0:1:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       usb0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       089c5a89-0609-3b55-aec6-81b99b828aa6
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.123.220/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.123.7
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.123.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.123.7, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.123.7
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.123.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3599
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.123.7
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.123.7
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        expiry = 1657701845
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        host_name = jose-Lenovo-B51-35
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        ip_address = 192.168.123.220
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        next_server = 192.168.123.7
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       routers = 192.168.123.7
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::c657:cf8d:c43d:5256/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   089c5a89-0609-3b55-aec6-81b99b828aa6 | Wired connection 2
 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-41-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:03:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --
 
##### NetworkManager.state ##############
 
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
 
##### NetworkManager config #############
 
[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
 
[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
 
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved
 
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma
 
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./
 
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
 
##### NetworkManager profiles ###########
 
##### Netplan config ####################
 
[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
 
##### iw reg get ########################
 
'iw' is not installed (package "iw").
 
##### iwlist channels ###################
 
lo        no frequency information.
 
enp3s0    no frequency information.
 
usb0      no frequency information.
 
##### iwlist scan #######################
 
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
 
enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
 
usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
 
##### module infos ######################
 
##### module parameters #################
 
##### /etc/modules ######################
 
##### modprobe options ##################
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode
 
[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
 
##### rc.local ##########################
 
grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory
 
##### pm-utils ##########################
 
##### udev rules ########################
 
##### dmesg #############################
 
[    9.452472] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[  266.544850] rndis_host 3-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:10.0-1, RNDIS device, <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]>
 
########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Maybe the driver is missing try installing a driver Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: If you believe this is the correct answer, why not vote to close as a duplicate?

Comment: I'm not very sure about it so i'm waiting for the reply

Comment: I strongly suspect that the answer at the duplicate will *NOT* resolve this question. Sorry.